# Canvas on a SurfaceView and an Object Below SurfaceView

Tags: android, button, canvas, surfaceview

I want to use the main screen of my app consists of 2 parts. In part one: there will be a surfaceview which is smaller than the whole screen size and it must be connected to a canvas. In the second part: there will be some objects such as buttons to interact. Any idea? Please don't want the codes because I tried too much, I googled it too much but I haven't found anything.

Comment: a SurfaceView locked to a Canvas? can you translate it into android vocabulary?

Comment: I want to use canvas to draw a bitmap into a surfaceview.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: I also wanna add some objects I told that in the question. I couldn't add a button below the surface, and I wonder how we can specify the canvas size? for example small portion of the screen.

Comment: Something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg ?  That's a SurfaceView (technically a GLSurfaceView, but that's a SurfaceView under the hood) that's sharing the screen with some controls.  If you keep an eye on the top-left you can see that there are TextView controls on top of the SurfaceView as well.  https://github.com/google/grafika

Answer (score 0):

if you can follow these tutorials i am sure you can find your answer [edu4java](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame.html)